# split fullname into first name and last name in postgres

Tags: postgresql

im confused about function to separate fullname into first and last name. for example i have these records

```
      fullname
     ---------------
         john
        john doe
     john nick doe
  john smith nick doe
```

i expect result like this

| firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- |
| john | john |
| john | doe |
| john nick | doe |
| john smith nick | doe |

can help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT
    fullname,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(fullname, '\s+\S+$', '') AS firstname,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(fullname, '^.*\s+(\S+)$', '\1') AS lastname
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used for the last name (the one used for the first name is a simplification of this):

```regex
^          from the start of the full name
    .*     match all content, greedily, until hitting
    \s+    the final space(s)
    (\S+)  then match and capture the final word in the full name (i.e. the last name)
$          end of the full name
```

Then, we replace with the captured last name, using `\1`.